# Checking property existence in complex interface fails

Tags: typescript

So I have the following interface:

```
export type MyConditional<R> = R extends null ? {} : {f: number };
export type Opts<R> = {smt: number} & MyConditional<R>;
```

My function accepts `Opts<T>` argument and inside the function I want to check if it has key `f`, and if it has, do something about it, like this:

```
function f<T>(opts: Opts<T>) {
    if ("f" in opts) {
        const r = opts.f;
        // do something with r.
    }
}
```

Problem is that this code does not compile, because `Property 'f' does not exist on type 'never'`. However, if I simplify my `Opts` interface a little, like this:

`export type Opts<R> = MyConditional<R>;`

Then it compiles. Why does typescript get confused by this intersection?

Comment: There's no interface here; instead you've got a value of a generic conditional type that you're trying to narrow when the generic type parameter is not yet specified.  There's some limited support for [unspecified generic narrowing added in TypeScript 4.3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-3.html#contextual-narrowing-for-generics) but I guess "intersection with conditional type" is not triggering it properly.  Could be a TS bug or limitation; haven't found an existing issue about it yet.